# jQuery sort multiple DIVs if contains <span> text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple sections in which I want to sort the `DIVs` if contains `<span>` text in it otherwise. I tried different `stackoverflow` threads but nothing helps for me so far, I am little near to my target but my code doesn't work I am not sure what I am doing wrong in it, these inner divs needs to be sorted inside each section. but I am not good at JS. 
If div contains the span text it bring it to first in each section.

```js
sortUsingNestedText($('#toSort'), "div.customCardData", "span.recenUpdate");

function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
  var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
    var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
    var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
    return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
  });
  parent.append(items);
  console.log("done");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mbr-justify-content-center" id="toSort">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center sectionTitle">
    <h2>Section Title 01</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item A</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item B</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item C</h3>
        <div class="ribbon"><span class="recenUpdate">Updated Today</span></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mbr-justify-content-center" id="toSort">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center sectionTitle">
    <h2>Section Title 02</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item X</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item Y</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item Z</h3>
        <div class="ribbon"><span class="recenUpdate">Updated Today</span></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/infohassan/1mbgpojq/3/)

Comment: There's several issues with your HTML and JS. However in order to fix them we need to know what exactly you mean by 'sort'. Given that there's only two divs containing `span` elements in the HTML example, should these be moved to the top or bottom? Also, what happens if you have to divs containing spans in the same gorup? How should they be separated?

Comment: I want to bring the span ones one first in each section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that you have created multiple elements with the same `id` of `toSort`. This is invalid as `id` *must* be unique within the DOM. If you want to group elements by common behaviour use classes instead.

> I want to bring the span ones one first in each section

In this case you don't need sort. Just `append()` the relevant `div` to the start of their group:

```js
$('.toSort').each(function() {
  var $h2 = $(this).find('h2');  
  $(this).find('.customCardData:has(span.recenUpdate)').insertAfter($h2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mbr-justify-content-center toSort">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center sectionTitle">
    <h2>Section Title 01</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item A</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item B</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item C</h3>
        <div class="ribbon"><span class="recenUpdate">Updated Today</span></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mbr-justify-content-center toSort">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center sectionTitle">
    <h2>Section Title 02</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item X</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item Y</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 mbr-col-md-12 customCardData">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Item Z</h3>
        <div class="ribbon"><span class="recenUpdate">Updated Today</span></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but can you make its jsfiddle?

Comment: Lolz when I copied the js and put it into my existing fiddle it didn't work :( but your code looks working

Comment: I figured out its a jQuery version issue, I am using 1.12.4 and it works with 3.3.1

Comment: Don't forget that you need to change the `id="toSort"` to classes. https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xkcs4r1n/

Comment: jQuery version won't affect this as it doesn't use any methods which have been changed in those versions. It works back to 1.9.1: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xkcs4r1n/2/. Probably further too, but that's as far as jsFiddle will go

Comment: Works perfectly God Bless You thanks for helping me out